# Extending AbpUserRoles to add new column - aspnetboilerplate

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I'm trying to extend `AbpUserRoles` in order to add new column into it. I was able to do that as following:

```
public class MyUserRole : Abp.Authorization.Users.UserRole
{

    public int MyCustomColumn { get; set; }

    public MyUserRole() { }

    public MyUserRole(int tenantId, long userId, int roleId, int myCustomColumnId)
        :base(tenantId, userId, roleId)
    {
        this.MyCustomColumn = myCustomColumnId;
    }
}
```

After above code, I added and updated migrations, and `MyCustomColumn` appeared in database.

**Questoin**: But I'm not getting how to use it. I tried registering it in my WebModule as `IRepository<MyUserRole>` and tried injecting it in `RoleManager`, but it did not work. I'm banging my head with this since last day, and seems there's something obvious I'm missing. Or it is not even possible?

Comment: this might help you https://aspnetzero.com/Documents/Extending-Existing-Entities

Comment: What do you mean by not working? You don't need to register the IRepository interface manually. Abp will resolve the correct entity when you inject MyUserRole repository using proper DI method

Comment: @ryan.c by "not working", i mean that MyUserRole repository is not injected. What do you mean by "proper DI method"? Please clear with example in answer.

Comment: Share you implementation of RoleManager and how you use it.

Comment: Did you add `DbSet<MyUserRole>`?

Comment: @aaron, I tried defining `IDbset<MyUserRole>` in MyDbContext class, but it did not help.

Comment: @ryan.c, The problem is that soon as I override UserRole as shown in question (even column is added in db after applying migrations) the abp doesn't seem to be reading the permissions correctly. And on starting application, I start getting `AbpAuthorizationException: Required permissions are not granted...`. Please guide me on this.

Comment: Create a repro project on GitHub.